# How do I send a scheduled message with telegram or facebook messenger via API?

Tags: facebook, scheduled-tasks, telegram

I want to send out scheduled messages using either telegram or facebook messenger.

I have found the API documentation for telegram.

https://core.telegram.org/

Though I have not found the part that explains to me yet.

Please advise.

Comment: There is no way to send Facebook messages using the API

Comment: reading two months and nothing till now if you find solution tell us

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at our REST API for Telegram at http://jaconda.im

We do not support scheduled messages yet, but you can do this with `cron` easily.

Just create an account with Jaconda, and you will be able to send and receive messages over HTTP calls.